# Sales prices on items

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, pricing

Is it possible to have both the standard price and sale price visible on the items tiles on a website?

I would like to have both prices visible and wanted to know if this was doable .

Comment: Is this in the context of a specific e-commerce plugin your site is using (i.e. Craft Commerce)?

Comment: hi Brad. Just seen this. It is in the context of craft commerce

Answer (score 2):

Yes simple use

```
{{variant.price}}
```

Or

```
{{variant.salePrice}}
```